# CellForRowAtIndexPath crashing on curly braces

Tags: swift, uitableview, io, stack-trace

I am using a table view in my project, the crashlytics reports are showing a crash in my cellForRowAtIndexPath function on the curly braces exactly which is not helping me to find the bug. I am not being able to reproduce this bug either on my device nor on the simulators. The stack trace is below and the cellForRowAtIndexPath code is attached as an image.

**Code**
[image: cellForRowAtIndexPath]

**Crashlytics Stack-trace**

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  Synkers                        0x104407d20 specialized HomeScreenViewController.tableView(UITableView, cellForRowAt :     IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell (HomeScreenViewController.swift:208)
1  Synkers                        0x104404134 @objc HomeScreenViewController.tableView(UITableView, cellForRowAt : IndexPath) ->     UITableViewCell (HomeScreenViewController.swift)
2  UIKit                          0x18a421474 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 668
3  UIKit                          0x18a4219d8 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 80
4  UIKit                          0x18a401670 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 2140
5  UIKit                          0x18a1bcf10 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 140
6  UIKit                          0x18a0e9000 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1256
7  QuartzCore                     0x184cb90b4 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 184
8  QuartzCore                     0x184cbd194 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 332
9  QuartzCore                     0x184c2bf24 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 336
10 QuartzCore                     0x184c52340 CA::Transaction::commit() + 540
11 UIKit                          0x18a0de884 _afterCACommitHandler + 256
12 CoreFoundation                 0x180c838b8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
13 CoreFoundation                 0x180c81270 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 412
14 CoreFoundation                 0x180c8182c __CFRunLoopRun + 1292
15 CoreFoundation                 0x180ba22d8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
16 GraphicsServices               0x182a33f84 GSEventRunModal + 100
17 UIKit                          0x18a14f880 UIApplicationMain + 208
18 Synkers                        0x104215ba4 main (main.m:14)
19 libdyld.dylib                  0x1806c656c start + 4
```

Comment: Pls add your code not the code image. And mention at which line your app is crashed.

Comment: I would assume your code is out-of-sync with the one deployed on the device.

Comment: I added the image to show the code lines; the app crashed at line 208. @dahiya_boy

Comment: My speculation is that somehow the switch executed the `default` case and it's returning an invalid cell, since it does not have an identifier.

Comment: @luk2302 never heard of it. can you add any reference to check. Thanks!

Comment: How many sections do you have in the tableview?

Comment: If you deploy your code on any device and then add e.g. a newline in your code in Xcode then the line numbers in the stacktrace will be off by one. That is what I mean.

Comment: @OzgurVatansever i have 3 sections

Comment: @luk2302 this is not the case the code showing is the line having the issue since I went back in git to the build i need

Comment: @KingT. remove `return UiTableViewCell()` and shift the code of case two into it. Bcz you can not return like this you must have to return Cell object not class. Pls check still any issue then try instead of switch do same with `if-else`. First try this and let me know what you getting.

Comment: I am returning a cell object not class! This will show an empty cell if the code goes there

Comment: @KingT. Try what i said, everything looked perfect, pls change and try.

Answer (score -3):

This has nothing todo with the error, but since my reputation is too low, i'll have to write an answere:

Never force-uncast a cell!

```
...forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ...
```

This may cause errors and even crashes

Comment: Not really. It is acceptable to force cast the cell if the programmer is sure it has the appropriate type. If it then crashes that is a bug that has to be looked at. You can and probably should force unwrap / cast whenever you have nothing else to do anyway. If you as the programmer cannot answer the question: "what should happen if it does not have the type", "what should happen if the image I bundled in the app cannot be found" a crash is correct. That way you at least realize there is a bug.